# Theorem on lim sup of max of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be iid random variables, then we are trying to prove that:
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \max_{k\leq n} \lvert X_k \rvert = \begin{cases}0 &\textrm{if  } E\lvert X_1\rvert < \infty \\
\infty &\textrm{if  } E\lvert X_1\rvert = \infty \\
\end{cases}$$

In the proof given in class, we proved that for all $a>0$:
$$P(\lvert X_n \rvert > an \ i.o.) = \begin{cases}0 &\textrm{if  } E\lvert X_1\rvert < \infty \\
1 &\textrm{if  } E\lvert X_1\rvert = \infty \\
\end{cases}$$
Using the above result, if $E\lvert X_1\rvert = \infty$, then it is obvious that $\limsup \frac{1}{n} \max_{k\leq n} \lvert X_k \rvert > a$ for all $a> 0$ which gives us the conclusion. But, if $E\lvert X_1 \rvert <\infty$, i don't understand how the previous result guarantees that $\limsup \frac{1}{n} \max_{k\leq n} \lvert X_k \rvert < a$, since we're always taking the maximum over all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have it figured out (can someone please verify this? or provide a simpler way if there is?):

If $E\lvert X_n\rvert < \infty$, then $P(\lvert X_n \rvert = \infty) = 0$. Consider the set $$\left(\bigcap_{n\geq 1} \{\lvert X_n \rvert < \infty\}\right) \cap \{ \lvert X_n \rvert > an \ i.o\}^c$$
This set has probability $1$ since it is the countable intersection of sets with probability $1$. Now, let $w$ be an element of the set above, then there exists $n_a$ such that $\forall n\geq n_a: \lvert X_n(w) \rvert \leq an$, and since $X_1(w),\ldots, X_{n_a-1}(w) < \infty$, there exists $n_0$ such that $$\forall n\geq n_0: 
 \frac{1}{n}\max \{ X_1(w),\ldots, X_{n_0-1}(w) \} \leq a.$$
This gives us the required result by considering $n\geq \max\{n_0,n_a\}$.

Comment: This is true but your last step is written in a confusing way.  That inequality holds for all $n \geq n_0$ not just because the $X_i$ are finite, but also because $X_n/n\leq a$ for all $n \geq n_a$ (and it seems you are implicitly assuming $n_a\geq n_0$ which makes the last line of choosing a max between the two also confusing).  Overall that last part could be explained better by adding more detail or steps. You may also need to add absolute value bars. [You could also simplify just by assuming $X_i$ are surely finite, since that follows by definition $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.]

Comment: There is also a final part that must show if $P[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \max_{i\in \{1, ..., n\}}\{|X_i|/n\} \leq a] = 1$ for all $a>0$ then $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\max_{i\in \{1, ..., n\}}\{|X_i|/n\}=0$ with prob 1.